# Local variable is nil, when it clearly shouldn't be (assigned to an expression with itself)

Tags: ruby, middleman

Why does this little code snippet (for a navigational helper with css classes) give me an `undefined method 'include?' for nil:NilClass` on the `elseif`-line?

The `page_classes_string` may be something like 'oddchap oddchap_zoidberg oddchap_zoidberg_index'. I think the purpose of this method is clear:

1. Get rid of the last word in the `page_classes_string` if it contains '_index'
2. Compare the `page_classes_string` to the current `page_string` and return a string with an appropriate class name for some navigation.

I tried this code in irb and of course it works, but not within my middleman config. I also could rewrite it by using a third variable that gets assigned my `page_classes_string', but that seems kind of cumbersome. Any suggestions?

*Of course the `_string`attached to the following variable names is for clarification purposes only.*

```
def nav_active(page_string)
  if page_classes_string.match(/_index/)
    page_classes_string = page_classes_string.split(/ /)[0..-2].join(' ')
  end

  if page_classes_string == page_string
    'active'
  elsif page_classes_string.include? page_string
    'semiactive'
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `page_classes_string`, besides in the conditional?

Comment: `page_classes_string` itself is a helper that contains a string with all names of the currently open page-tree concatenated and is definitely never empty.

Comment: Check again - it's clearly `nil` at least sometimes. Is `page_classes_string` the name of a method? If so, you should probably avoid assigning a value to a variable of the same name.

Comment: I guess I got the scope of vars wrong. Thought inside my method I can use every name that I like, even if it is assigned to a helper, outside of my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest getting rid of the `page_classes_string` and simply make a new class to hold your css classes. Depending on how you are currently generating the `page_classes_string`, I don't imagine this would be too disruptive:

```
class PageClassCollection
  attr_reader :css_classes

  def initialize(*classes)
    @css_classes = classes
  end

  def to_s
    css_classes.join(' ')
  end

  def non_index_classes
    css_classes.select {|c| !c['_index']}
  end

  def nav_active?(page_string)
    return 'active' if non_index_classes == [page_string]
    return 'semiactive' if non_index_classes.include? page_string
    nil
  end
end
```

You would use it like this:

```
page_classes = PageClassCollection.new('oddchap', 'oddchap_zoidberg', 'oddchap_zoidberg_index')
page_classes.nav_active?('oddchap') #=> 'semiactive'
```

If you still need to convert it into a string, `.to_s` takes care of that (it will be called automatically if you use string interpolation, e.g. `"#{page_classes}"`).